# Mesh disappears in edit mode after rig but visible in object mode

Tags: mesh, rigging

When I try and edit the mesh in edit mode after rigging, only the rig shows. The mesh does show only in object mode I have attached one screenshot in object mode and 1 in edit mode.[image][image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/OwvwV5xJ

Comment: You've hidden the mesh, press alt H to unhide

Comment: Whoops! Thank you